# What does "indiscrete marriage" mean in the context of this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does *indiscrete* make sense in the following sentence? Is this word used as synonym of *indissoluble*?

> The instincts and conduct of the young man who aspires to the eminence
>   of a dukedom, from which he seems hopefully removed by the precedence
>   of several relatives and an *indiscrete* marriage which his mother made,
>   are elegant and impeccable.

— [The New York Times, *Books* (Alec Guinness Plays 8 Roles in 'Kind Hearts and Coronets," at Trans-Lux 60th Street)](http://www.nytimes.com/books/97/08/24/reviews/guinness-coronets.html).

---

Oxford Dictionaries, *indiscrete*: "not divided into distinct parts".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me this is more likely to be a misprint for *indiscreet* — lacking discretion; unwise.

IMDb has this for the plot of *Kind Hearts and Coronets*:

> Louis Mazzini's mother belongs to the aristocratic family D'Ascoyne, but she ran away with an opera singer. Therefore, she and Louis were rejected by the D'Ascoynes. Once adult, Louis decides to avenges his mother and him, by becoming the next Duke of the family. Murdering every potential successor is clearly the safest way to achieve his goal...

...and I guess an opera singer was thought to be rather *infra dig*.

Answer (score 5):

They've used the wrong word:

> ***[indiscreet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indiscreet)***: *not discreet; imprudent or tactless*

is the word they meant to use.

Comment: +1. Most likely. Both *discrete* and *discreet* have the same origin and pronounciation, BTW.

Comment: Also note DavidC's observation that he was probably _hopelessly removed_, not _hopefully removed_ from the dukedom.

Answer (score 0):

To say that a marriage was indiscreet was a polite way of saying that it lowered the social status of the one entering into it. How exactly this makes it harder for the young man to receive a heritary title is not clear to me.

Also, I think the author meant to say that the young man was "hopelessly removed" not "hopefully removed" from a dukedom.

Comment: This is wrong. A marriage which lowers social status might be ***indiscreet,*** not *indiscrete* (as other answers point out).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks, I will correct the spelling error. It looks like I copied it from the original quote.

Answer (score 0):

While it is likely that you would use indiscreet to describe a marriage (and it is likely that this is the context in which it was meant in the above quote,) it is also entirely possible to describe a marriage as indiscrete, which would be the same as describing a marriage as indivisible.